# Android :Media player plays only https audio links (http is not working)

Tags: android, cordova, audio

I am develop an android application in cordova in which it has an audio player implemented using this plugin http://arielfaur.github.io/ionic-audio/

Its works only in https audio url files and not in http audio urls.

Here is the sample audio json file

```
$scope.tracks = [
            {
                url:'https://ionic-audio.s3.amazonaws.com/Message%20in%20a%20bottle.mp3',
                artist: 'Genesis',
                title: 'Land of Confusion'
            },
            {
                url: 'http://uploads.com/church/uploads/audio/01_-_Pat.mp3',
                artist: 'Gen',
                title: 'Tonight. Tonight. Tonight'
            }
        ];
```

Comment: Please check out this working cordova sample app using media plugin - https://github.com/gandhirajan/Cordova_Media Hope it helps

Answer (score 1):

```
<access origin="*" />
<allow-intent href="http://*/*" />
<allow-intent href="https://*/*" />
```

add these lines in your config.xml.